# Visual Studio 2008 C++. Problem Referencing DLL Project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, dll, reference

I've got a solution with two projects in it: one is a simple dll with a simple class (dll_test).  The second project references the dll project and is supposed to be used to test the dll project (dll_tester).  The dll project builds fine, but the tester project always complains about not being able to find dll_test.**lib** instead of dll_test.**dll** like it's supposed to.

Again, this is with Visual Studio 2008 on a Windows 7 machine.  I don't think it makes a difference, but I started the solution with the dll_test project and added the dll_tester project later.

Does anybody know how to resolve this?

Comment: Just to clarify, did you add **dll_test.lib** to Properties->Linker->Input and its path to Properties->Linker->Additional Library Directories?

Comment: No, I didn't.  But it's not supposed to be creating a lib, it's supposed to be creating a dll.

Comment: You need to have the header files, the DLL file *and* its corresponding LIB file to statically reference to a DLL project. The actual code is in the DLL of course, but the LIB file is needed so the linker can link to the DLL statically. When you compile your DLL project, the linker should create DLL file(s) and their LIB file(s).

Comment: Hmm, ok.  I'm not seeing any LIB files anywhere though.  I looked in all of the Debug folders for the solution and the individual projects.  Maybe I should compile once for dll and once for lib?

Comment: That's probably because you forgot to export functions from the DLL.  Dumpbin.exe /exports on your DLL shows you.  You have to use __declspec(dllexport) to export functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, the joys of DLLs and dependencies in Visual Studio.  I swear, C# coders have it easy :)

Are you certain that the LIB file is actually created?  If your DLL project does not export any symbols you won't get a lib file, and ergo you won't have anything to link to.  So you need to make sure that:

1. Your DLL Project defines something like `MYPROJECTNAME_EXPORTS`.  Visual Studio defines this symbol for you when you check the appropriate box when creating the project.  If you did not do this, it's quite simple.  Ensure that the aforementioned symbol is in the preprocessor directives for your DLL, and in a common header file ensure that the following is defined:

   ```
   #if defined(MYPROJECTNAME_EXPORTS)
   #define MYPROJECT_API __declspec(dllexport)
   #else
   #define MYPROJECT_API __declspec(dllimport)
   #endif
   ```
2. Once we know that that `MYPROJECT_API` is appropriately defined, we need to make sure that any class or function that we wish to export, has that in it's declarations:

   ```
   class MYPROJECT_API SomeClass
   {
   }; // eo class SomeClass
   ```

And that class needs to be implemented and actually *do* something that the compiler has not optimized away.

In short, the reason you cannot find a `.lib` file is because none was generated because no symbols were exported from it.

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  I can't believe I forgot to export something :^)

Answer (score 0):

right click the dll_tester in solution explorer and look "Project dependencies..." and make sure that the dll project is checked